# run same job in same node or different node in Jenkins

Tags: shell, version-control, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a job running on a node A, and trying to run that same job in different node or same node @ same time, I made # executors 4 still it is not doing waiting for the current job to complete. Any idea appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, there is a plugin for that, I was looking for, Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin,

Please some one could let me know why I got -1? I asked my doubt I am sorry if this is not an appropriate?